# How to write ARG_MIN in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

I am trying to re-write the following `arg_min` expression in Isabelle (2020) into the more convenient ARG_MIN syntax.

```
lemma "1 = arg_min (λ(x::int). x*x) ((<) 0)"
```

What I have so far is:

```
lemma "1 = (ARG_MIN ((x::int)*x). 0 < x)"
```

But it's giving me an "Inner syntax error".

*I am just wondering what the correct way is to use ARG_MIN above.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the syntax translation from ARG_MIN (found by C-click on arg_min, and looking a few lines after that definition):

```
translations
  "ARG_MIN f x. P" ⇌ "CONST arg_min f (λx. P)"
```

You want to have `arg_min (λ(x::int). x*x) (λx. x < 0)`. So matching what P, x, and f are, the notation becomes:

```
ARG_MIN (λ(x::int). x*x) x. (x < 0)
```

Comment: Urgh, that syntax is horrible. I think I will change that to something more palatable in the next few months, perhaps `ARG_MIN x∈A. f x` or in this case `ARG_MIN x | x < 0. x * x`.

Comment: Please do! The syntax does not give me any intuition about what is going on here. (But I don't use such things anyway).